# Why do these two processes behave like this?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm creating two instances of a process over here but when I'm running this program I'm getting only main function output.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def sleepy_man():
    print("Starting to Sleep")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Done Sleeping")

tic = time.time()
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=sleepy_man)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=sleepy_man)
p1.start()
p2.start()

toc = time.time()

print("Done in {:.4f} seconds".format(toc-tic))
```

**Output**

```
Done in 0.0554 seconds
```

I was doing it for practice from this blog only.
Source: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/04/a-beginners-guide-to-multi-processing-in-python/

Comment: shouldn't you wrap your process definition and start() in "if __name__=="__main__"?

Comment: It's generally a good idea to have `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard for all multiprocessing code even on forking systems. Regardless, what's the culprit here is probably the main process ends before all sub-processes have a chance to spawn and print their output. Make sure you `.join()` your processes before exiting your main process to ensure they finished execution,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is worth noting you would see the same behavior if you had somehow set `p1.daemon = p2.daemon = True`.

It is also possibly due to output buffering, rather than logic errors.
Two questions:

- If you add a `sys.stdout.flush()` or `flush=True` to your `print`, do you see different behavior?
- If you run this with `time python foobar.py` does it take .02s or 1s to run?

Obviously, continuing your tutorial and correctly adding `.join()` below will resolve the issue in a way that would be expected for normal usage.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time


def sleepy_man():
    print("Starting to Sleep")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Done Sleeping")


# if you are on Windows, which use spawning to create child processes, use __name__ == '__main__'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tic = time.time()
    processes = [
        mp.Process(target=sleepy_man),
        mp.Process(target=sleepy_man)
    ]
    [p.start() for p in processes]
    # if you want to see results of process work, join them
    # otherwise if main process finish its work before their children
    # you'll get no results since parent process will finish children 
    # you can also declare Process as daemon=False - as another choice
    # in that case you can use no join()
    # on the other hand join() makes parent process to wait for children join()
    # and only then it prints time in your case
    [p.join() for p in processes]
    toc = time.time()
    print("Done in {:.4f} seconds".format(toc-tic))
```